# Evaluate $\iint_E xy\ dx\ dy$ over the region $E$ common to the circles $x^2+y^2=x$ and $x^2+y^2=y$ using change of variable

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have solved the problem just by taking limits in $y$ first, then in $x$ and got the answer ${1\over 96}$ i.e.
$$\iint_E xy\ dy\ dx=\int_{x=0}^{1/2}\int_{y=\left(1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}\right)/{2}}^{\sqrt{x-x^2}}xy\ dy\ dx={1\over 96}.$$ 
[image: Graph of x^2+y^2=x and x^2+y^2=y]

**But the author asks to use the change of variable-

$${x^2+y^2\over x}=u$$ and $${x^2+y^2\over y}=v$$**

But I cannot get the limits of $u$ and $v$, I am also facing problem to find the Jacobian as we need to find $x$ and $y$ explicitly.
Can anybody solve the problem using the change of variable? Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Comment: For the jacobian all you need to do is find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$,...,$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ i.e. all 4 partial derivatives and make a matrix out of them, then find the determinant.

Comment: As for the limits, $x^2+y^2 = y \iff v = 1$, and $x^2 + y^2 = x \iff u =1$, So your $u,v $ is between $0$ and $1$. The lower limit would be at the origin i.e $x^2+y^2 = 0$.

Comment: I can find ${\partial u\over \partial x},\cdots$ but I need to find ${\partial x\over \partial u},\cdots$.

Comment: you just invert the matrix to get those derivatives (inverse function theorem)

Comment: Notice that you can rewrite the circles as $(x-0.5)^2+y^2=0.25$ and $x^2+(y-0.5)^2=0.25$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interiors of the two circles are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2
+
\left(y-0\right)^2
&\le
\left(\frac 12\right)^2
\ ,\text{ or also }
&
x^2+y^2&\le x\ ,
\\
\left(x-0\right)^2
+
\left(y-\frac 12\right)^2
&\le
\left(\frac 12\right)^2
\ ,\text{ or also }
&
x^2+y^2&\le y\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and in the intersection of the discs we have as in the picture $x,y\ge 0$.

It is natural to use the given substitution, and first we note:
$$
\begin{aligned}
u&:=\frac 1x(x^2+y^2)\in[0,1]\ ,\\
v&:=\frac 1y(x^2+y^2)\in[0,1]\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
The values $u,v=0,0$ being taken for instance in $x=y=0$, and the values $u=1$, $v=1$ on the one or other circle (disc boundary).

By connexity of the domain of all $(x,y)$, we get all values between $0$, $1$ for both $u,v$. Of course, these and only these values can be taken, so $(u,v)\in[0,1]\times [0,1]=I\times I=I^2$, here $I=[0,1]$ for short.

Now 
$$\frac 1{u^2}+\frac 1{v^2}
=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}  
+
\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
=
\frac 1{x^2+y^2}\ ,
$$
so we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &=\frac{\ \frac 1{1/u^2+1/v^2}\ }u=\frac{uv^2}{u^2+v^2}\ ,\\
y &=\frac{\ \frac 1{1/u^2+1/v^2}\ }v=\frac{u^2v}{u^2+v^2}\ ,\\[2mm]
dx &= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{uv^2}{u^2+v^2}\right)\; du
+
\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{uv^2}{u^2+v^2}\right)\; dv
\\
&=
-\frac{(u+v)(u-v)v^2}{(u^2+v^2)^2}\; du
+\frac{2u^3v}{(u^2+v^2)^2}\; dv\ ,\\
dy &=
+\frac{2uv^3}{(u^2+v^2)^2}\; dv
+\frac{(u+v)(u-v)u^2}{(u^2+v^2)^2}\; dv
\ ,
\\
dx\wedge dy
&=
-\frac 1{(u^2+v^2)^4}\Big[ (u+v)^2(u-v)^2u^2v^2+4u^4v^4\Big]\; du\wedge dv
\\
%&=
%-\frac 1{(u^2+v^2)^4}u^2v^2\Big[ (u+v)^2(u-v)^2+4u^2v^2\Big]\; du\; dv
%\\
&=
-\frac 1{(u^2+v^2)^4}u^2v^2\Big[ (u^2-v^2)^2+4u^2v^2\Big]\; du\; dv
\\
&=
-\frac 1{(u^2+v^2)^2}u^2v^2\; du\; dv
\\
\ ,
\\
xy\; dx\; dy
&:=
|xy\; dx\wedge dy|
\\
&=
\frac {u^3v^3}{(u^2+v^2)^2}
\cdot
\frac 1{(u^2+v^2)^2}u^2v^2\; du\; dv
\\[2mm]
\iint_Exy\; dx\; dy
&=
\iint_{I^2}
\frac 1{(u^2+v^2)^4}u^5v^5\; du\; dv
\\
&=
\iint_{I^2}
\frac 1{(u^2+v^2)^4}u^5v^5\; du\; dv
\\
&=
\frac 14
\iint_{I^2}
\frac 1{(U+V)^4}U^2V^2\; dU\; dV
\qquad\text{(using $U=u^2$, $V=v^2$)}
\\
&=\frac 14\int_0^1\frac 13 V\; dV\left[\left(\frac U{U+V}\right)^3\right]_{U=0}^{U=1}
\\
&=
\frac 14\int_0^1\frac 13 \frac V{(1+V)^3}\; dV
=
\frac 14\int_0^1\frac 13 \frac {(1+V)-V}{(1+V)^3}\; dV
\\
&=
\frac 14\cdot\frac 13\cdot \frac 18
=\frac 1{96}\ .
\\[3mm]
&\text{Just as an observation, we can also compute and check the area:}
\\[2mm]
\iint_E 1\; dx\; dy
&=
\iint_{I^2}
\frac 1{(u^2+v^2)^2}u^2v^2\; du\; dv
\\
&=
\frac\pi 8-\frac 14
\\
&=2\left(\ \pi\cdot\left(\frac 12\right)^2-\frac{(1/2)^2}2\ \right)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where the integral was computed with [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), see code below, and the last result, twice a parenthesis, is the geometrical answer, immediately seen. (The parenthesis is quarter of area of disc with radius $1/2$ minus the area of the triangle...)

---

Sage code:

```
sage: var('u,v');
sage: integral( integral( u^2*v^2/(u^2+v^2)^2, u, 0,1), v, 0, 1)
1/8*pi - 1/4

sage: # also
sage: diff(u*v^2/(u^2+v^2), u).factor()
-(u + v)*(u - v)*v^2/(u^2 + v^2)^2
sage: diff(u*v^2/(u^2+v^2), v).factor()
2*u^3*v/(u^2 + v^2)^2

sage: diff(u^2*v/(u^2+v^2), u).factor()
2*u*v^3/(u^2 + v^2)^2
sage: diff(u^2*v/(u^2+v^2), v).factor()
(u + v)*(u - v)*u^2/(u^2 + v^2)^2
```

Comment: Something went wrong in editor, i wanted to compute both $\iint_E xy\; dx\; dy$, and the area  $\iint_E 1\; dx\; dy$... have to retype

Comment: Now it is fixed.